# Wordpress Theme and PHP version

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working in local environment with a Wordpress MU installation that is currenly working live in my client's servers. He needed it SPAM cleaned, updated, etc.

Problem is with one of the sites using what it seems to be a custom made theme. Trying to access the admin section takes you to a blank page, and if you go to the site you first get a "call to undefined function" error. I managed to fix it removing the "&" from the functions, and I get to show the page except that it displays an "Illegal string offset Warning" in every place a post should be showing. And I'm lost.

Problem is in this line:
`get_template_part('content-'. $args['template'] );`

from this function:

```
function the_loop($args = NULL){
    global $IDS, $loop;
    $loop = get_all_articles(&$args);
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            get_template_part('content-'. $args['template'] );
            $IDS[] = get_the_ID();
        endwhile;
    } else {
        get_template_part('content-not-found');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $loop;
}
```

Any ideas??
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`$args` is probably a string:

```
php > $args = 'foo bar baz';
php > echo $args['template'];
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'template' in php shell code on line 1
```

`var_dump($args)` to confirm... It should undoubtedly be an array, which means you need to look upwards in the call tree, wherever this function is getting called.